# Prevent variable overwrite into submakefile

Tags: linux, makefile, environment-variables, overwrite

I have a makefile compiling a shared library which I call from another makefile.

When developping the library I used the variable `TARGET` to name the library binary.

```
BUILD_DIR?=$(abspath ./build)
SRC=src/file.c
INC=-I inc

CFLAGS+=-Wall -Werror
LDFLAGS+=-Wl,--no-undefined

TARGET=libname

ifndef ARCH
  $(error Undefined ARCH (Library targetted architecture))
endif

default: all

all: ${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}/${TARGET}

${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}/${TARGET}: ${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -fPIC -shared -o $@.so ${SRC} ${INC}

${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}:
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf ${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}/${TARGET}

.PHONY: all clean ${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}/${TARGET} ${BUILD_DIR}/${ARCH}
```

However, into the parent makefile, I use the variable `TARGET` to specify the board on which I'm deploying the app.

```
ifeq (${TARGET},target1)
    # Target1 compiling
    ${LIB}:
        scp $@ ${TARGET_USR}@${TARGET_IP}:
        ${SSH_CMD} make -C $@ ARCH=arm
    [...]
endif
ifeq (${TARGET},target2)
    # Target2 compiling
    ${LIB}:
        make -C $@ BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR} CC=${CC} ARCH=${ARCH}
    [...]
endif
```

I'm compiling as follow: `make TARGET=target2` and I'm using GNU make

Compiling the library from the parent makefile succeed but the name of the library is `target2.so` instead of `libname.so`.

I thought variables were passed to submakefiles only if explicitly precised on the command call (as for `BUILD_DIR`, `CC` and `ARCH`) but it seems that `TARGET` is also passed to sub makefile.

I know that I could just do `override TARGET=libname` into the sub makefile.
But I would like to know if there is another solution.

Comment: You should explain how you set `TARGET` at the top-level. In the Makefile? On the command line? Through an environment variable? And once you answered this question, you should probably read the [relevant section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion) of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) (assuming it is your make). And, by the way, you should probably also read [the section about the `MAKE` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) and stop using `make` in your recipes.

Comment: What is wrong with the `override` solution?

Comment: Nothing at all, I just have many libraries using the same scheme and I thought maybe there is a solution allowing to do it from the parent makefile. It's just curiosity... and some laziness though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, any command line variable arguments will override any local assignments in the makefiles.   There is a way around this by using the [override](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html#Override-Directive) directive:

```
override TARGET := libname
```

This will set the variable in the child makefile, regardless of whether the value was specified on the command line.

Comment: I knew this solution, this is what I'm doing right now but I wanted to know if there was another solution

Comment: In newer versions of make, there is an `override undefine` directive [described here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Undefine-Directive.html), which might do what you want it to do (3.81, which is what I use, does not support it).    Outside of this, use a name that is less likely to conflict, or set `TARGET` in the environment rather than on the command line...